# How to really stop NGINX forever on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

On my web server running **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS** obviously nginx was installed and is running:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      967/nginx: master p
```

However, `kill 967` will make it re-spawn again.

I tried all that I could find to try the service to stop, but nothing works:

`service stop nginx`
*stop: unrecognized service*

`systemctl kill nginx.service`: *Failed to kill unit nginx.service: Unit nginx.service is not loaded.*

`sudo nginx -s quit`: *sudo: nginx: command not found*

`sudo service status nginx`: *status: unrecognized service*

`grep -r nginx /etc/init`: empty result

I can't even uninstall it:

`sudo apt-get remove nginx`: Package 'nginx' is not installed, so not removed

Where can I find this nginx service and how to stop it?

Update:

```
ps -ax | grep nginx

  967 ?        Ss     0:00 nginx: master process /opt/opscode/embedded/sbin/nginx -c /var/opt/opscode/nginx/etc/nginx.conf
  970 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
  971 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
  972 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
  973 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
  974 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
  976 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
  977 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
  978 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
  979 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
  980 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
  981 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
  982 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
  983 ?        S      0:00 nginx: cache manager process
 1252 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
 3060 ?        Ss     0:00 runsv nginx
 3072 ?        S      0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/opscode/nginx
```

Comment: @num8er this file does not exist

Comment: `ps -ax | grep nginx`

Comment: I think it's running supervisord

Comment: I've updated my question with the "ps -ax" output

Comment: it's using supervisord, see last line in ps

Comment: ok, thanks. How to stop it? :)

Comment: it's done using `supervisorctl`

Comment: supervisorctl: command not found

Comment: there is also no supervisord.conf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208801/discussion-between-num8er-and-delete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by comments we come to point that there was `chef` running nginx and preventing it from close (crash and etc).

since server owner does not want to use chef, we decided to uninstall it:

```
chef-server-ctl uninstall
```